# Read 3 integers from file c++

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I want to read mulitple variables from a file and store them in a object, but its not working.

File example:

```
De vedettn 
Wout Wouters
14 7 2005
```

Code that i wrote:

```
string naam, leider;
int dag, maand, jaar;
ifstream myfile ("file_ploeg.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
    cout << "Entering file" << endl;
    while ( myfile.good() )
    {
        cout << "Entering while" << endl;
        getline (myfile,naam);
        cin >> dag >> maand >> jaar;
        getline (myfile,leider);
    }
    Datum* datumOBploeg = new Datum(dag,maand,jaar);

    Wielerploeg* wielerploegOB = new Wielerploeg(naam, *datumOBploeg,leider);
    myfile.close();
    cout << "\n";
    return wielerploegOB;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're reading your lines out of order (at least according to your example file).

```
while ( myfile.good() )
{
    cout << "Entering while" << endl;
    getline (myfile,naam);
    cin >> dag >> maand >> jaar;
    getline (myfile,leider);
}
```

Should be:

```
while ( myfile.good() )
{
    cout << "Entering while" << endl;
    getline (myfile,naam);
    getline (myfile,leider);        // reordered this line
    myfile >> dag >> maand >> jaar; // use myfile instead of cin
}
```

Also, if I were you, I'd review the rest of the code in your function and make sure you're not abusing pointers.

Comment: Thank you :) I was just that stupid that I didn't saw that. And myfile instead of cin is also a good tip!